# What is the iOS7 equivalent to HTML radio buttons?

Tags: ios, user-interface, uiswitch, uipicker

I want the user to select his gender. Is there an iOS7 equivalent to HTML radio buttons?
I find the iOS switch awkward for gender selection and a picker view overkill...

Comment: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/46143/has-ios-7-changed-the-appearance-of-radio-buttons

Comment: How can you say that I find the iOS switch awkward for gender selection? Its not you but the whole lot more users gonna use your app. and Apple also recommends to use it in their guidelines.!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS segmented buttons can help you:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html

Or a custom one:
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/segmented-buttons

Comment: why not use the native `UISegmentedControl` implementation though?

Answer (score 0):

There is `no default` class to create feature like HTML radio button. But you can customize with button by showing images depends on click(On/Off).